# ExtJs 6 access record on checkcolumn listener invocation

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am trying to access the record of the row when a checkbox is clicked.

Here is some code extract:

```
Ext.define('SomeList', {

  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  mixins: {
    field: 'Ext.form.field.Field'
  },
  xtype: 'myXType',
  requires: [...],

  columns: [
    {
        header: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        width: 50
    },
    {
        header: 'Checked?',
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'checked',
        width: 120,
        listeners: {
            checkchange: function( component, rowIndex, checked, eOpts ) {
                console.log('checkchange', component, rowIndex, checked, eOpts);
                // how to access the table's column record here?
            },
        },
    }
],
...
```

I feel blocked and I do not find anything about it on the internet.
Is there a common basic thought mistake I am doing?

I am using ExtJS 6.0.0 classic.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);`** in **`checkchange`** event handler.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2knb)